# How to split array based on an element value in bash

Tags: bash

I have an array say `a=(one two three split_array four five)`. I need to find  `split_array` based on a know substring `split` and finally get all the items before it i.e `one two three`. Is there any way to achieve this by using parameter substitution. I can do it using loop but looking for smarter way to achieve this.

Comment: Efforts at achieving terseness here are going to be doing so at the expense of correctness -- not generally a worthwhile tradeoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is smart but you can once concatenate the array into a string and perform the parameter substitution on it:

```
declare -a a=(one two three split_array four five)
b="${a[*]}"
declare -a c=( ${b%% split_array*} )
for i in ${c[@]}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

the output:

```
one
two
three
```

- `b="${a[*]}"` merges the elements of the array to a space-delimited string
- `${b%% split_array*}` removes the pattern " split_array*" of $b

*Note that the script above is based on the assumption that the elements of the array do not contain IFS characters.*

For such a case you can modify the `IFS` to a character which may not be used in the elements of the array, e.g. the escape character:

```
ESC=$'\e'       # the escape character
declare -a a=("one word" two three split_array four five)
ifs_bak=$IFS    # back up IFS
IFS=$ESC        # new delimiter
b="${a[*]}"
declare -a c=( ${b%%${ESC}split_array*} )
for ((i=0; i<${#c[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${c[$i]}"     # test output
done
IFS=$ifs_bak    # retrieve IFS
```

the output:

```
one word
two
three
```

It may not be still 100% guaranteed that the escape character is never used in the array elements. There is always a *risk* when we merge an array into a string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will split `a=("one word" two three split_array four )` to have `one` and `word` as two separate entries; and `a=( "*" split_array )` will have the `*` replaced with a list of files. Much less buggy if you do the split *inside* the `for` loop.

Comment: You're right. I should have mentioned I have assumed each element of the array does not contain whitespaces/tabs. Otherwise the script above will not be reusable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering Perl, check this

```
>  perl -e '@a=qw(one two three split_array four five);for(@a) { last if /split/; print "$_\n" }'
one
two
three
>
```

If exporting as a variable,

```
> export a="one two three split_array four five"
> perl -e ' @a=split / /, $ENV{a}; for(@a) { last if /split/; print "$_\n" }'
one
two
three
>
```